# redisClient.set :- no update no error

Tags: heroku, redis, updates, redistogo

```
redisClient.get('abc', function(err, abcValue){
 console.log(abcValue);
 abcValue = abcValue + 'id';
 redisClient.set('abc', abcValue, function(err){
  console.log('abc updated');
 });
});
```

nested updation over network, prints 'abc updated', but actual value does not update in redis database.

Note:- the above code works on localhost, but update not showing on heroku-redistogo.

Edit:- I'm running code on localhost, with redis connected to Redistogo. Using the following code:-

Setting up of express session:-

```
app.use(express.session({ 
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'birdeye.redistogo.com',
        port: 1384,
        db: 'redistogo',
        pass: '052940128c2f2452f73378588dd5fb129'
  }),
     secret: '1234567890QWERTY',
}));
```

I am also creating another redisClient using the following code:-

```
var redisClient = require('redis').createClient( 1384, 'birdeye.redistogo.com', {detect_buffers: true});
redisClient.auth('052940128c2f2452f73378588dd5fb129', function() {
    console.log('Redis client connected');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see `abc updated` inside the console when running this code on Heroku ? It seems to be a misconfiguration of Redis client.

Comment: I'm seeing `abc updated` in the console. I'm putting more code in the edit.